# Can't access (ping, tracert..) from cmd but works from putty

Tags: windows, ping, putty, windows-command-prompt

I am not able to ping or tracert to a remote machine from windows command line, but I am able to ping/tracert and access same machine when using putty on same windows machine.

What can I do to access from command prompt as well?

Answer (score 0):

Do these commands work if you try and run them from the command line in Windows\System32?

Make sure %SystemRoot%\system32; is in your PATH environmental variable (system properties -> advanced -> environment variables -> path).

Comment: Yes, those commands work on my command prompt. And PATH is correctly set as well.